# How to override a method depending on a constructor?

Tags: java, methods, constructor, interface, overriding

Okay, so I'm not sure if this question already exists because I don't know how to format it, but here's the problem: can a same method produce different result depending on a constructor? (I apologize if I'm repeating the question or if it's a stupid question.)

For example, let's say that I have an interface `MyInterface` with function `public void foo();`. Let's say we have class:

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    public MyClass() {
        // I want foo() to print "Empty constructor" with sysout.
    }

    public MyClass(int x) {
        // I want foo() to print "Constructor with int" with sysout.
    }
}
```

So now, if create two references `MyClass mc1 = new MyClass();` and `MyClass mc2 = new MyClass(5);` and then call `mc1.foo();` and `mc2.foo();`, the result should be:

> Empty constructor.
>
> Constructor with int.

I tried with `new MyInterface { @Override public void foo() { ... } }` inside constructors but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: So you want to different methods? A guard variable? Two different classes

Comment: Are you doing this for fun? What's the point?

Comment: Short answer yes, but you need to write the code, for example, you could use a instance field `private Integer value;`, in your `public MyClass(int x)` constructor, you would assign the value of `x` to `value`; `value = x`.  Then in `foo`, would test `value` to see if it was `null` or not; `if (value == null)`, when `value` is `null`, you would print `Empty constructor.`, when it's not, you could print `Constructor with int.`; as an example

Comment: @MadProgrammer, as I mentioned with a guard variable. Very ugly, I see no real reason for it, but who knows, I might be wrong.

Comment: Well, I just want to know if it's possible. I want same method to do different things depending on constructor (for example, returning PI from Java library on empty constructor and doing Monte Carlo method when passing an argument of number of dots).

Comment: @Emz It would all come down to needs and context, as I said, it was just an example of one possible way of achieving the result - there's a reason why it's not an answer

Comment: @MadProgrammer, "Very ugly, I see no real reason for it, but who knows, I might be wrong." was not directed at you or your comment, the idea in general.

Comment: So you want different behavior depending on what you call to create an object.  That *really* sounds like you want two different classes that both implement the interface.

Comment: @Emz No issue from my end, the context is light on the ground :P - probably making the question to broad

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Store the variable and check it in the foo method.

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    private int x;
    public MyClass() {
        // I want foo() to print "Empty constructor" with sysout.
    }

    public MyClass(int x) {
        // I want foo() to print "Constructor with int" with sysout.
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void foo(){
       if(x > 0)
          System.out.println("Constructor with int");
       else
          System.out.println("Empty constructor");
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I use `new MyClass(-10)`, it will print `Constructor with int`

Comment: If a user instantiates the class with `<= 0` this won't work. I recommend using some sort of `Object`, like an `Integer`, just check against `null`.

Comment: Well you could store a boolean that indicates whether it used that constructor. Or you could make the int be an Integer and instead of checking for greater than zero, check for whether it is null. It will be null for the default constructor.

Comment: That could also work and would be the most graceful, making the `boolean` `final` as well.

Comment: @Emz What would the difference between using another (`boolean`) variable and a `Integer` to store the value?  You could make `x` `final` and still end up with the same result, just with a single variable

Comment: An extra variable, that is set to `true` in the `MyClass(int x)` while `false` in the other, then match against that one instead of `x > 0`

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question: Not to my knowledge. Or at least not directly, you could start to read byte code and change it during run time, make it adapt-- so again, the answer is no.

Now the weird parts are the `override` and `depending on constructor`. It is not in the scope of [overriding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding).

A method doing different things depending on the state of the `Class` is not too odd. However, making the method unique of how the class was instantiated I've never heard of. That being said, here is a fairly ugly solution to it.

```
public class Test
{
    private final boolean intConstructorUsed;

    public Test () {
        intConstructorUsed = false;
    }

    public Test (int x) {
        intConstructorUsed = true;
    }

    public void foo () {
        if (intConstructorUsed == true) {
            // do this
        } else {
            // do that
        }
    }
}
```

The `foo` method isn't *that* weird. The weird part is that you basically have to different implementations of `foo` depending on which constructor, you are sure you do not want an `abstract class` behind, with all shared methods except for one `abstract void foo ()` that you override? Sure the classes will almost look identical, however they are not, as they do not share their `foo ()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's what's multiple constructors are designed to allow for - variation via object creation.

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    private final String message;
    public MyClass() {
        message = "Empty constructor";
    }

    public MyClass(int x) {
        message = "Constructor with int";
    }

    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

It's even threadsafe.

The thing to note here is that the implementation of the method is exactly the same, the variation is in the constructor. And it's the constructor which is called differently depending on what the caller wants to happen.